# How to translate words from this story about a tiger?

Tags: translation

> 他看到草地上有一团圆乎乎略带红色的东西

> 谁知一阵刺痛袭来， 老虎的鼻子被这团东西卷住了

I can almost translate the first one, but I don't know what 圆乎乎略 means. I don't even know if I cut this sentence into words correctly...

The second one is, unfortunately, unapproachable. "谁知一阵刺痛袭来" - no idea what it means. "卷住" - this is strange, because Google Translate says it means "roll up", but in this sentence it's a tiger who gets "rolled up" by spikes of a hedgehog. I don't get it at all.

Could you, please, put spaces in correct places in these sentences and explain them?

Comment: Problem with parsing: "圆乎乎" is one unit; "略带红色" is another unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[他] [看到] [草地上] [有一团] [圆乎乎] ，[略带红色的] [东西]

[He] [saw] [on the grass] [there was a bundle of] [roundish] ，[that slightly contain red color] [thing]

> 他看到草地上有一团圆乎乎，略带红色的东西

> He saw there's a bundle of roundish, slightly red thing on the grass

*"圆乎乎，略带红色的" is the adjectival phrase for the object "**东西**" --> "roundish, slightly red "**thing**"*

[谁知] [一阵刺痛] [袭来]， [老虎的] [鼻子] [被这团东西] [卷住了]

[Who know = unexpectedly] [a sharp pain] [struck]， [the tiger's] [nose] [was by this bundle of thing] [coiled around]

> 谁知一阵刺痛袭来，老虎的鼻子被这团东西卷住了

> Unexpectedly, a sharp pain struck, the tiger's nose was coiled around by this bundle of thing